# JavaFx TableCellFactory - get Object or ColumnIndex

Tags: javafx

Maybe a simple question, but somehow I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

I'm trying to create a dynamic table (dynamic column count) using dynamic fields. Each cell should be an object, containing not only the raw text but also information like background color, etc. So far this works but for a small thing: I need the according object while processing it in cellFactory. Object item is the value String, not usable for this. getTableRow().getItem() is better, it is at least the according row (ObservableList<>). Is there a better way to get the item? Or how do I get the column index?

```java
public class FXTableColumn {

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
    public static TableColumn<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object> createColumn(
      final int columnIndex, String columnTitle) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object> column;
        column = new TableColumn<>();
        column.setText(columnTitle);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<CellValue>,Object>,ObservableValue<Object>>(){   
               public ObservableValue<Object> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object> param) {                        
                        return param.getValue().get(columnIndex);                       
                    }                   

                });

        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object>,TableCell<ObservableList<CellValue>,Object>>(){
            @Override
            public TableCell<ObservableList<CellValue>,Object> call(TableColumn<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object> p) {
               return new TableCell<ObservableList<CellValue>, Object>(){
                   @Override
                   public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                         if(item != null){

                              // so here is my problem, item is a String, not the input object

                              super.updateItem(item, empty);
                               if( getTableRow() != null ) {
                                    Object cellValue =  getTableRow().getItem();
                                    //this is better, but not perfect: this object contains now the ObservableList<CellValue>
                                    //how can I get the actual item? Or, how do I simply get the column index(which also is the index of the observableList?)

                                }
                         }  
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        return column;
    }



}
```

(CellValue implements ObservableValue)

Comment: What is `CellValue`? Can't you just design that class so that the item you get in the `updateItem` method has all the data you need? And isn't the column index the value that's already passed into your `createColumn(...)` method?

Comment: Using the row data and the column index is not really that good a solution though; if you set things up correctly (i.e. stop using raw types and write the model so the appropriate type is available to your cell) it shouldn't be necessary to do that.